# Read Binary Data from IsolatedStorage in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

I have some bytes written to a file in isolated storage in my Silverlight application. This file is named "data.dat". I wrote it to Isolated Storage using the following code:

```
// Store the data in isolated storage
var bytes = GetData();
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("data.dat", FileMode.Create, storage))
  {
    file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  }
}
```

My question is, how do I retrieve the bytes from isolated storage once they're there? Everything I see returns a string. But I don't see a way to return binary data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code will retrieve the bytes -

```
byte[] output;

using (IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   IsolatedStorageFileStream isolatedStorageFileStream = isolatedStorageFile.OpenFile("data.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

   output = new byte[isolatedStorageFileStream.Length];
   isolatedStorageFileStream.Read(output, 0, output.Length);
   isolatedStorageFileStream.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Leon - I think it's meant to be 'output'. So either change 'data' for 'output', or change byte[] output; to byte[] data;